# How does PROMELA execute this?

Tags: c, spin, promela

```
byte x;

if
::(x == 0) -> ...
::(x > 0) -> ...
fi
```

Is there a default value of a global variable? Or the model checker checks for all possible interleavings, that is, in this case, use all possible states with both `(x==0)` and `(x>0)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Promela doc](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Quick.html) variables are initialized to zero by default.

Checking for all possible initial values of variables would increase the state space exponentially.

Comment: But how can I make the model checker to check for all possible states, that is, in this case for both (x==0) and (x>0)?

Comment: Can you elaborate how?

Comment: SPIN is (IIRC) `explicit-state` model checker (maybe they added some symbolic verification, but I am not sure as it would be recent), so the models are executed as they are defined. You are probably looking for some parametrization and verifying those two options in two different launches of the model checker.

Comment: Read this, http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/rand.html. According to that, If the variable is declared inside a process, all its values are tested by the model checker in verification mode. Precisely, what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this;

```
if
:: x = 0
:: x = 1
:: x = 2
// if you need more, add more
fi
```

or if you really want all values, 0 to 255

```
byte x = 0;

do
:: x <= 254 -> x++
:: break
od
```

which will break or increment on each iteration, thus generating all possible values.  Or, as you (and I) now know, use:

```
select (i : 0 .. 255)
```